# How long does js file cached?

Tags: javascript

I know there are Cache-Control commands in php, like

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=86400');
```

https://www.keycdn.com/support/cache-control

But without these commands, how long does js file cached? If I edit js file, sometimes I have to use Ctrl + F5 to renew, to download, to take effect. Now I'm wondering an user, after how long time his browser renew js files?

Comment: If you don't specify any preference, then this probably depends on the browser and user settings.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is very active using the browser, the length of time that the cache is stored can be extended to 10 minutes or less

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).